# Receiving syntax error when calling stored procedure

Tags: mysql, node.js, openshift, mysql-error-1064

```html
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS checkExistingEmail;
delimiter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE checkExistingEmail(
 IN parmEmail VARCHAR(100)
,IN parmFName VARCHAR(100)
,IN parmLName VARCHAR(100)
,IN parmPassword VARCHAR(60)
,OUT RetVal TINYINT
,OUT UID VARCHAR(36)
) 
BEGIN


 IF EXISTS (SELECT email FROM User_Registration WHERE email = parmEmail) THEN
     SET RetVal = 0; 
        SET UID = null;
    ELSE
  
        SET UID = UUID();
        SET RetVal = 1; 
        
        INSERT INTO User_Registration(Email,FirstName,LastName,Password,GUID)
        VALUES(parmEmail,parmFName,parmLName,parmPassword,UID);
 END IF;
END
```

I'm receiving a SQL syntax error but I cannot figure out what the problem is. The problem is only occurring when I push my application to OpenShift. It runs fine locally both in my express app and in the MySQL Workbench.

It doesn't make any sense because I can execute this statement within in PHP Admin console.

I'm using MySQL 5.5.

```js
==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log <==
POST /register - - ms - -
checking user: bob@me.com
call checkExistingEmail('bob@me.com','Bob','Dole','$2a$10$wlZ345NAAyLAU2PawLJN6eBTXg7T3qftX0L7gU/5DYjxpFw6RUnd2',@RetVal,@UID);SELECT @RetVal as retVal,@UID as uid;
Error: { [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @RetVal as retVal,@UID as uid' at line 1]
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }
```

This is show that it works locally.

```js
checking user: bob@me.com
call checkExistingEmail('bob@me.com','Bob','Dole','$2a$10$CboZR8mlMacNlMzyUKHVVuEn5t.Yx9tphyqBNG8wO1GnKVd2K54E2',@RetVal,@UID); SELECT @RetVal as retVal,@UID as uid;
[ OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 1,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 10,
    warningCount: 0,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0 },
  [ RowDataPacket { retVal: 1, uid: '76f54340-82be-11e6-9304-182b925c144f' } ] ]
POST /register 302 267.012 ms - 92
```

Comment: Any ideas as to what could be causing it? I even tried removing the aliases for the return values and even placed `` around them. Still receiving the same error.

Comment: I've added the procedure

Comment: `SELECT @RetVal as retVal,@UID as uid` is not in that proc

Comment: I do not understand why I need that in there. It works fine in PHP admin without that. I can still see the output.

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with the stored procedure because it works. It does exactly as it should be doing. I'm running 5.7.13 locally and the application is executing the procedure and returning my results just fine. I do not need to add a SELECT statement within the stored procedure if I am defining output parameters.

Comment: Your stored proc sets 2 `OUT` params. It does not return a resultset. The error msg you are showing shows a resultset attempt. It looks like a mismatch of versions / a conversion. Old code that did it one way, then changed to `OUT` ... I have no idea

Comment: So basically don't use output parameters. Just use a result set instead. I can work with that.

Comment: they are more compatible by a country mile across all types of apps. Try getting c# clients to read out parameters. Takes a guy 2 hours first time :p

Comment: Sounds pain full. I was able to get the result set to return. Thanks for the tip! Another reason to like MS SQL server.

Comment: Marketshare. Another reason to like `mysql` :p